# Why is the ajax function not executing when I click on the 'like' image?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a picture of a like button, when clicked, should update the score by 1.
I am using ajax to execute this.
However, when I click the image nothing happens. When I hover my mouse on the image, the pointer does not even change to a hand.

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"></link>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>

    Welcome: <?php
        // Start the session
        session_start();
        //Use session variable created in login.php
        echo $_SESSION['username'];
    ?>

    <div class="friend">
    <?php
        while($row = $res->fetch_assoc())
        {
            echo "<image class='img' src='images/" .$row['image'] . "'></image>";
            echo "<div class='info'>";
            echo $row['name'] . "<br>";
            echo $row['surname'] . "<br>";
            echo "SCORE: " . ($row['likes'] - $row['dislikes']);
            echo "</div>";


        }       
    ?>

    <div class='friend_actions'>
            <image class='button' id='likes' src='images/like.jpg'></image><br>
            <image class='button' id='dislikes' src='images/dislike.jpg'></image>
    </div>

</body>
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

    $('#likes').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'likes.php',
            type:'post',
            data: {id: $('#id').val()},
            success: function (result) 
            {
                //Reload the current document
                location.reload();
            }

        });

});
```

**likes.php**

```
<?php
    require "php/conn.php";

    $db->query("UPDATE friends_list SET likes = likes + 1 WHERE id = 1");
?>
```

Comment: The hand issue is because it's an image, not a a link (`a`-tag). You could add: `#likes:hover {cursor: pointer;}` to solve that.

Comment: For hand pointer, you should use `#likes:hover {cursor: pointer;}`

Comment: What do you get in the developer console when you click on the image?

Comment: Can you confirm that `likes.php` is getting the called from the console? Does your console show any error?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: There you go. Something _does_ happen when you click on it. You should use an absolute path to the `likes.php`-file. like: `/likes.php` (if the file `likes.php` is in the document root).

Comment: 1) `Welcome: <?php session_start(); ?>` will throw an error if you allow `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` (do that on all pages) and you'll get more info if any other error... 2) `id: $('#id').val()`-> where's the input with ID `id` and is it unique ? 3) add also `error` on jQuery side 4) check console 5) why `WHERE id = 1` if you use multiple ID's ?

Comment: `$('#id').val()`  i am unable to see any element with id=`id` . Also you have only one-like/dislike button for all images? or  like/dislike buttons per images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Here syntax error in script writing check 
this your code    
$(document).ready(function () {    
$('#likes').click(function() {   
    $.ajax({   
        url: 'likes.php',  
        type:'post',  
        data: {id: $('#id').val()},  
        success: function (result)   
        {  
            //Reload the current document  
            location.reload();  
        }  
});  //this end of ajax
}); //end of like event function
 where is document end ? 
 you can not complete document '});' so complete document function
```